# Подскажите технологию для карты

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день.

Интересует технология с помощью которой можно было бы создать данную карту участков.
Суть такова: при наведении на участок выводиться стоимость и фотография.
Хочется сделать такого же типа, но при наведении и отдалении можно взглянуть на остальные улицы, где уже нет продажи участков(сделать это для того что бы ориентироваться по местности территории на которой смотришь карту, как в яндекс картах примерно, но увеличение будет ограничено).
Интересующий меня вопрос:
Технология по которой можно сделать такую же карту, как на картинке. (технология написана на сайте [http://новыеморки.рф/](http://xn--b1agjhjdhds0i.xn--p1ai/) )

Пишу данный сайт о продаже участков используя html, css и ванильный js.
Была идея заполнить данные участки svg фигурами и при наведении уже выводить информацию о стоимости и т.д. Но не придумал как можно с помощью css разметить эти фигуры таким образом, ведь блоки идут ровные, а тут фигуры разного типа и разложить их в правильной последовательности будет очень сложно.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: берёте карту и добавляете поверх слой svg

Comment: Все что вы хотите, есть здесь: https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам пример с любой формой объектов, хоть полигона, хоть дугами (как элемент *Decentraland*).

Карта составлена из основных регионов Германии, точность очень сильно округлена для снижения объёма кода svg.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('g path').forEach(region => {
  // Хак z-index внутри svg
  region.addEventListener('mouseenter', event => {
    document.querySelector('g').appendChild(event.target);
  });
  // Обработка клика по элементу карты
  region.addEventListener('click', event => {
    // Нацеливает фокус
    document.querySelectorAll('g path').forEach(region => {
      region.classList[region == event.target ? 'add' : 'remove']('selected');
    });
    let box = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    let sbox = document.querySelector('svg').getBoundingClientRect();
    // Считаем координаты центра
    let cx = (box.left + .5 * box.width - sbox.left) / sbox.width * 591.504;
    let cy = (box.top + .5 * box.height - sbox.top) / sbox.height * 800.504;
    let popup = document.querySelector('#popup');
    // Двигаем popup
    popup.setAttribute('d', `M${cx} ${cy}l-20-20h-80v-40h200v40h-80z`);
    // Включаем отображение
    popup.classList.add('show');
    let text = document.querySelector('#text');
    // Устанавливаем координаты текста
    text.setAttribute('x', cx);
    text.setAttribute('y', cy - 40);
    // Сам текст берем из атрибута id элемента, по которому кликнули
    text.innerHTML = event.target.getAttribute('id');
    // Включаем отображение
    text.classList.add('show');
  });
})
```

```css
svg {
  max-width: 100vw;
}

g path:hover {
  fill: #e7ffe7;
  stroke: #f00;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}

g path.selected {
  fill: #478f47;
}

#popup,
#text {
  display: none;
}

#popup.show,
#text.show {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<svg overflow="visible" style="transform:scale(1)" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 592 801" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g fill="#e7e7e7" stroke="#000" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width=".37px">
    <path id="Decentraland" d="M 314 22 A 60 60 0 0 0 233 94 A 110 110 0 1 1 86 22 A 300 300 0 0 1 314 22 Z" style="transform:scale(.5)"/>
    <path id="Thüringen" 
      d="m312 352c21-3.1 4 28 40 24 14 11-2.7 24 26 33 15 3.2 51 23 30-12 46 21 22 31 4.4 40 11 19-9.7 24-18 20 3.1 15-10 30-31 19-5.5-22-18 0.49-15 14-5-1.6-25-20-34-4.2 20 13-14 18-13-3.5-10-8.4-22-20-32-20 9.7-20-20 3.2-4.8-21 9.6-12 0.6-26 16-26-13-13 13-13-9.5-23-23-16 21-27 28-33 5.2 7 10-3.2 13-6.9z" />
    <path id="Schleswig-Holstein" 
      d="m322 114c-17 13-3.6 24 2 34-6.7 27-43 35-45 4 2.1-34-27 19-40-4.5-1.2-28-39-20-41-41 18-2-8.2-15-2.6-27-40-1.5 39-15 3.1-35-19-15-13-41 13-25 15 13 34-8.8 46 12 19-4.2 8.9 32 1.1 32 17-15 19 12 21 5.2 19-8.2 32 21 50 1 20 26-37 30-8.2 44z" />
    <path id="Sachsen-Anhalt"
      d="m366 208c11 9.8 25 15 40 19 1.4 19-9.9 32 5.8 43-13 26 6.8 47 31 45 20 1.2 41 34 7.1 33-38-5.7-57 31-36 63-2.4 22-45-7.9-52-10-5.6-12-0.34-30-27-26-11-9.3-12-26-26-29-6.3-21-11-38 18-39 14-16 0.93-35-0.19-49-12-17-17-33 6.1-37 19 8.2 24-1.7 33-13z" />
    <path id="Sachsen"
      d="m462 347c16 4.3-3 26 23 23 26 11 32 4.9 47-12 26-12 58-6.9 58 27 3.1 20-19 61-26 23-17-11-26 2.3-13 10-29 16-57 27-79 44-13 13-50 9-54 36-7-16-42-25-20-45 4.3 16 27-5.2 15-17 18-8.4 35-18 9.7-30-30-7.2-20-61 14-57 6.2-5.2 17 1.1 25-2.2z" />
    <path id="Saarland" d="m26 560c18 8.5 62-23 58 14 15 8.2 3.4 25 1.6 32-19 1.7-20-15-37-7.9-1-18-23-27-22-39z" />
    <path id="Rheinland-Pfalz"
      d="m145 448c1.9 19-19 21-2.1 41-12 2.6-35 37-2.9 28 21-8 24 29 19 39 13 25 2.4 41-9.4 67-22-4.3-59-12-62-30 13-12-9.6-17-3.4-32-15-21-59 19-55-8.8 23-24-38-30-14-61 9.6-20 30-9.3 40-16 9.3-26 48-22 64-45 7.9-24 17 20 26 18z" />
    <path id="Nordrhein-Westfalen"
      d="m232 351c-9.3 17-19 22-33 15 11 16-36 12-18 25 14-3 1.8 23-9.5 17 2.7 23-27 22-29 39-9.7-17-19-35-29-7.5-21 9-42 15-59 32 7.8 9.6-35 10-25-3.7-12-8-15-26-21-40 18-9.4-26-25 3.7-28 13-7.2-5.4-13 12-27 5.5-19-34-58 9.8-50 6.2 2.8 44-2.8 27-20 16-18 49-20 59-37 19 6.9 19 24 18 37-8.1 11 46-0.49 33-17-18-13 1.2-28 14-22-1.2 33 38-19 24 15-13 5-5.8 22-2.2 20 8 16 29 32 21 53z" />
    <path id="Niedersachsen"
      d="m177 149c-7.3-22 9.4-33 26-23 28-19 37 34 59 41 18-1.2 44 11 64 10 6.6 18 33 26 37 33-3.4 23-68 0.75-40 37 7.6 19 10 34 11 52-8 16-39 6.2-27 29-6 7.6 13 42-13 29-8.9 22-47 13-45 30-24-5 12-40-23-36 12-24-15-29-16-51-18-5.2 17-52-11-26-18 8.6-14-28-33-5.5-10-1.4 22 41-13 34-11 9-25 6-14-3.9-5.5-15 0.3-24-18-31-5.2-4.3-42 39-40 6.1 2.6-17-34-3.6-19-28 34 5.8 27-44 34-68 5.1-2.5-27-4-11-21 7.5-20 63-33 69-1.2-20 12 24 19 4-1.7 5.3-17 32 24 23-5.3zm28 50c-12-2.2-44-21-20 0.044 2.7 12 23 18 20-0.044z" />
    <path id="Mecklenburg-Vorpommern"
      d="m322 114c17-11 42 13 40-13 2-9.4 47-6.8 51-34 4.7-15 49 0.66 17-3-21-6.3-25 34-11 7.6 17 2.4 32-19 37 7.2 19 6.2 16 24 36 11 15 16 1.5 46 34 38 3.6 16 23 55-5.3 50 22-25-17-8.4-21-26-15 19-24 33-45 36-20 10-56-30-75 0.029-19-3.2-26 26-44 2.8-0.59-19-50-8.7-21-29 31-22-21-23 7.5-48zm141-78c-13 19-0.42 0.52-0.52 7.9-3.2 0.35 29 9.4 8.2 9.7-22-15-3.2 12-17 17 8.4 15 19 12 23-0.92 20 0.35 13 2.2 4.1-14 19-16-22-5.8-11-21zm34 51c-5 3.1 3.3 26 9.9 10 13 16-9.7 1.3-3.2 19-6.8 9.5 39-5.5 8.1-16-4.5-5.4-14-4.5-15-13z" />
    <path id="Hessen" 
      d="m262 379c8.4 16 26 19 14 31 14 14-18-0.31-4.7 18-9.2 11-18 32 0.017 26-0.64 29-34 31-38 57-21-14-42 3.2-27 27 9.7 21 0.45 34-18 43 13-12-11-15-11-23-3 24-26-8-14-16-3.9-18-13-34-34-20-24-17 33-27 6.1-47 5.4-13 12-14 8.8-32 9.4-11 30-18 29-36 19 4.2 14-21 2.6-19 6.6-14 28-6.9 25-23 17 21 31-32 46-5-4.5 6.6-13 28 4.8 25-3.9-7.6 11-16 11-6.1z" />
    <path id="Hamburg" d="m251 155c4.8-6.9 40-29 26 0.58 28 24-25 14-26-0.58z" />
    <path id="Bremen" d="m204 199c-14-1.8-44-20-20 1.6 4.3 12 23 16 20-1.6z" />
    <path id="Brandenburg"
      d="m538 171c8.9 27-36 50 4.8 65 28 9-2.7 39 21 49 6.2 21-12 41 6.3 60-15 13-43 4.9-52 28-17 2.7-38-1.2-47-5.9-1.2-16-10-18-3.4-33-4.5-28-53-9.3-60-40 10-20 0.36-31-4.4-41 7.7-17 3.6-31-20-31-6.6-16-61-19-22-23 4-16 28-13 38-24 26 9.8 54 24 70 5.9 18 11 24-49 38-19 23-6.7 19 6.9 15 18 9.1 3.2 8.6-8.5 16-8.4zm-59 73c-23 0.59-23 38 6.1 25 35 16-2-34-6.1-25z" />
    <path id="Berlin" d="m479 244c16-1.6 34 40 2.4 25-27 9.4-25-22-2.4-25z" />
    <path id="Bayern"
      d="m393 475c16 17 23 36 41 51-15 20 11 49 27 57 21 16 36 36 56 46 16 5.2 14 51-12 32 0.96 32-38 29-49 53 17 9.2 16 29 17 38 19 1.2-1.4 46-13 11-4.1-17-30 6.6-37-13-1.9 23-40 8.2-54 24-14 17-38 14-44-0.97-18-2-34-11-28 13-4.7 12-25 20-15 1.2-13 3.3-20-29-40-17 5.7-16 49-2.8 32-36 9.7-24-24-58 15-65-9.3-16 2.1-18 11-15 4.5-31-32-44-24-76-1.7-21-18 6.3-18-21 1.5-17-22 1.9-14-15-10 2.1-31-0.96-16 9.7-5 10-31 19-19-5.7-15-18-9.9-58 22-36 6.1-18 21-28 37-40 16-26 37 35 46 24 17 3.3-16-19 13-15 10 3.9 26 20 21-4.3 6.9-24 18 19 39 1.6z" />
    <path id="Baden_Württemberg"
      d="m207 563c13 0.78 26-11 16-20 20-5.5 15 8 33 7.3 2.5 19 10 24 18 21-0.91 24 11 44 24 64-1.9 17 6.7 24-13 20 17 24-36 22-12 48 2.9 17 5.5 43-1.1 57-23 5-47 10-64-13-18-9.9 22 23-7.2 11-16 12-39-31-42 2.1 27-7-1.5 19-12 3.2-21 6.6-53 15-49-15 1.6-26 10-47 17-71 9.7-31 42-52 51-83 6.7-13-12-38 10-27 0.54-19 7.6 9.3 17 6.6-18 25 21-9.2 15-8.9z" />
  </g>
  <path fill="#fff" stroke="#00f" stroke-width="4" id="popup"/>
    <text  id="text" y="0" x="0" alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">Text</text>
</svg>
```